# Sizeof(Array) Prints wrong value

Tags: c, arrays

I have initialized an array of size 10 but on printing the sizof array shows  40 . The code is as follows  ,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int  arr[10] =  {2,4,5,6,7,8,9,6,90};

        printf("%d \n" , sizeof(arr));

}
```

Output :

```
/Users/venkat/Library/Caches/CLion2016.1/cmake/generated/InsertionSort-e101b03d/e101b03d/Debug/InsertionSort
40 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What does C prints 40 here ?

Comment: Use  `printf("%zu\n" , sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);`. `%d` is used for `int`.

Comment: [See the C documentation here.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4)

Comment: `using namespace std;` is not valid standard C code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof`returns the size of the array in memory, not the length of the array. Then since `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes and your array has 10 int values, its size is 40.

Comment: And note that sizeof returns a size_t, and must be printed using the "%zu" format to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Your array contain 10 ints.
`10 * sizeof(int)`

int *here* is `32 bits = 4 bytes.`
4*10 = 40. Simple math

Answer (score 1):

Because `sizeof` is a built in operator that works on the type of the expression. For arrays (and not pointers) it will print `sizeof(array_element_type) * array_length`.

On your system, it must be that `sizeof(int)` is 4.

And once you get excited over learning that

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) == array_length
```

bear in mind that once you pass the array into a function, it will decay to a pointer and that will no longer hold.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide sizeof (arr) by the size of one element:
sizeof (arr)/ sizeof (arr[0])

This because sizeof(arr) shows the number of bytes the argument is made of, i.e. sizeof(int) * array dimention